# After transferring website - PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-management, config, file-transfer

I am transferring website from one host to another.
A very strange error occurred that I haven't seen before.

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

I thought that this was a wp memory limit issue so I added this to my wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '8096M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '8096M' );
```

But the website keeps returning error 500, and this error in my error log.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Find the code that's causing the error. The error should at least give you the script that's causing it.

Comment: I found it but no help, i tried deleting it, then it pointed me to another part of code so i can't delete the whole wp-core-functions of woocommerce. The problem must be elsewhere. @aynber

Comment: @Epodax, couldn't be really more specific ahahah

Comment: @aynber Hitting the memory limit isn't always the fault of the code that finally hits the limit - it can be a "straw that broke the camel's back" scenario. 40 MB is a very low memory limit, particularly for something memory-heavy like WP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Wordpress PHP file(s) :**
Try to add `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` on pages that causes the error (or in a PHP file included on all pages)

OR

**In php.ini** : Search the php.ini file read by your PHP server and try to increase the `memory_limit` parameter (never set this key at `-1` because it can freeze the server if you (really) have a problem in your code).